# Azure ADF - HTTP : Table from list

Tags: list, azure, api

I'm new with ADF.
I use a HTTP request (ex: myapi/users) to return a list of user id in a dataset delimitedtext:

This first request is not a JSON Array because of an error when i use a JSON Format, it return a simple text list:
[image: Text list]

I need to convert this list in a new sql table:

```
USERID
6
8
15
18
....
```

Then I want to use this table for a new API REST request to return details of each users with a foreach capacity for each UserId in parameter

ex: myapi/users/{userid}

At the end I want to copy data in a new SQL Table:

```
USERID  |  FIRST NAME  |  TYPENO   | 
  6           NAME1         123
  8           NAME2         A125
```

I try to use the scenario of this tutorial
[REST API TUTORIAL](https://youtu.be/zrn-MkCgG0M)

Thanks

Comment: can you explain a bit more about your ask with a sample input and expected output?

Comment: `[6,15,21,30,26]` is a JSON array. You should be able to use ForEach to loop aroud that. What have you tried? I can't find any good examples online right now

Comment: You don't need to turn it into a table. It's a JSON array, you can use ForEach directly with that. Inside the ForEach you can call the REST API and inserrt a row into a database table. Please give it a try. Please expand on _This first request is not a JSON Array because of an error when i use a JSON Format_ you might need to convert it from a string or put curly braces around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with **@Nick.McDermaid** that there is no need to convert it into table.

> This first request is not a JSON Array because of an error when i use a JSON Format, it return a simple text list: [image: Text list]

As per the above, you have used a HTTP linked service and it might be the reason for you to get the dataset like above.

If you are not able to resolve the error, you can try like below as a workaround. Give the HTTP linked service to a lookup activity.  As per the above preview of dataset, it will give the output like below.

[image]

Now, convert this string into an array using this expression `@json(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Prop_0)` to use in Foreach. I have stored the array in a set variable.

[image]

Using this array in ForEach, you can get it done your requirement with a dynamic URL REST API(use `@item()` in it) as source to copy activity and SQL table as sink.

**(OR)**

You can try a web activity for first HTTP URL which will give the required JSON array.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your answer.
For the first API request when I use a REST or HTTP in JSON format I got the error:

`Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file '4124139b-d732-4031-a4a7-154b4c991037'. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
Activity ID: 2aaed1c7-077e-4feb-b7cc-0bd0ef25579d`

Comment: as the error suggests `Check if the data is in valid JSON object format` check your JSON format. If still the error persists, try my approach with delimited text for HTTP as a workaround or you can raise a new ask on your error so that the community may assist.

Comment: It's a third party API so I can't modify the format of the request's return.